# Call Jquery library only for specific tasks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm scraping a news website with PHP and injecting the Jquery library in the head, along with my own script which depends on Jquery. I have experienced some loss of functionality regarding some websites. So I was wondering if it would be possible to make the Jquery library function only for my script and thus not "assimilating" itself with other scripts on the page.

I have Googled for this but all I can find is Jquery noConflict() but it doesn't get the job done.

Comment: Maybe you are addressing the wrong issue here. Why do you lose functionality? Did you check what causes it?

Comment: @Joseph the Dreamer I would like my code to be somewhat "universal" and work for other websites. All I know is that Jquery library is causing the problems, I do not need to know "exactly" what is going on, this will be different for any other website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery noConflict is the way to go but remember you will need to name your no conflict copy and then use this copy of jQuery for your code:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// $j is now an alias to the jQuery function; creating the new alias is optional.

$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j( "div" ).hide();
});
```

See more here: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: Doesn't work for me, but +1 and I will accept answer if nothing else comes along because I think there is really nothing else that "fits" my question.

Answer (score 1):

What about editing jQuery library itself so it is called something else.

1. Embed the jQuery object via PHP to not have this huge chunk of jQuery code (more readable if you can inject with PHP, but not required, or use a script tag that points to your server).
2. Customize jQuery to be not "jQuery" or "$".

Then, to customize jQuery, download jQuery and look at the very bottom, it says:

```
// Add your customized jquery here
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

Change this line to something else:

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
window.myQuery = window.$$$$$$$$$ = jQuery;
```